# React Router Conditional Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

This is my Route config that is working nicely.

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
  <Route path="city">
    <Route path=":city" component={City} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="country">
    <Route path=":country" component={Country} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

it works for urls  example.com/city/london and example.com/country/england

now i want to change it so that when user types

example.com/london  -> City,

example.com/england -> Country

How do i go about setting my Route now?

Comment: Added a sample working demo. Please check update

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you have a component route which will decide which component to render based on the route params.

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
 ...
 <Route path=":place" component={CommonRoute} />
 ...
</Route>
```

In your `CommonRoute` component you would need some logic to identify whether the `param` is city or country.

```
...
componentDidMount() {
    let param = this.props.match.params.place;
    ...
    //Logic to decide what place is. i.e (city or country)
    //set the store state accordingly
    ...
}
...

render() {
  return(
    ...
    this.props.reducerName.isCity && </City>
    this.props.reducerName.isCountry && </Country>
    ...
  )
}
```

Well, this just an idea. I would suggest you try and let know, if these works. Hope this helps.

**Update:** Here you go. [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-y55bga?file=index.js)

Comment: Seems like that would work. But is there any drawbacks? like history stacks or other perf related issue?

Comment: I agree that is might lead to some performance drawbacks, only in the case where you are trying to manipulate state in your componentDidMount() fn. Buts other than that, I don't see any drawback.
Nowhere in docs, it is mentioned that it is bad practice to set state in componentDidMount() fn. But they have surely mentioned about some extra rendering.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: In your case I think componentDidMount() fn is the only suitable place for adding logic to work on route param. Other that I don't see any drawback

Comment: This works great, but now it is really bad for SEO. It is now only server rendering the routing page..